# LARAVEL 8 - Enviando Tokens a través de AJAX -> Error 419 y 500

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax, laravel-8

Tengo un problema con esto, estoy aprendiendo a enviar desde Ajax a Laravel un formulario para el Controller y no sería problema si no existieran los Tokens. Muestro mi código y agradezco la ayuda!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me funcionaba poner el headers: en ajax, así que lo puse con un $.ajaxSetup y si soy sincero no sé muy bien como funciona, pero ya me pasé por todo stackoverflow jajaj

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    })
    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,

        success: function(response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log("funcionó");
            } else {
                console.log("la concha de mi madre");
                console.log(response);

            }
        },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    })
```

Si lo coloco de otra manera, me sale error 419, caso contrario 500.

Esta es mi función route(user.cotizar) ->

```
    public function cotizar(Request $request){

        $validator = validator($request->all(), [
            'carro' => 'required',
            'pastillas' => 'required',
            'caliper' => 'required',
            'ubicacion' => 'required',
            'ejes' => 'required',
            'marca' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response();
        }

        $correo = new CotizacionMailable();
        Mail::to('pablojavierprietocepeda@gmail.com')->send($correo);


    }
```

Por si alguien entiende algo de laravel.log, les dejo los logs de cuando sale error 500
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ACTUALIZACIÓN -> puse para que si ajax retorne error, en consola salga "error" xd.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ACTUALIZACIÓN 2 -> Si pongo esto en el jquery me vuelve a salir error 500.

```
$.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log("funcionó");
            }
        },
        error: function(response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    })}
```

puse esto en la plantilla blade ->

Comment: El error esta en tu controlador, deja el token como meta, asi como esta a lo ultimo, en el validator fails prueba con un reponse asi: return response()->json('Invalid data',400);